# how to let my web-ui communitate(or control) my CLI program

Tags: python, sockets, webui

I'm already implement a command line tool used for 802.1x authentication in python. But I want a gui frontend. I want to try a web UI this time, but I don't know how to let my webui communicate with my python app.
I only know that I need to open a socket in CLI program and receive the message send by the web ui. But I'm a newbie in web development. I don't known what to do with my web app.
Do you have any good advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Python official wiki [page about web programming](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebProgramming) and the wikipedia [list of the web frameworks written in Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Python) are good places to start from.